# Android How to Show direction on mapview

Tags: android, google-maps

Hello everyone I am developing a prayer app in which I have to show custom map marker which will show kaba direction from current location. I have lat/lang of kaba and i have to rotate or any other method which will tell user that kaba (holly mecca) is in this direction.

Basically I am using needle or arrow as my marker option to show kaba direction. I have also angle of Kaba from current position. I have searched but not found any Satisfactory answer.

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update `CameraPosition` with the `target location`,`bearing` and `tilt`.

Comment: @MD I have searched dear

Comment: @Rustam can you give me any example link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following method to point the direction towards destination.

```
     private void updateCameraPosition() {

            Location startingLocation = new Location("starting point");
            startingLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude()); // location is current location
            startingLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

            //Get the target location
            Location endingLocation = new Location("ending point");
            endingLocation.setLatitude(destination.latitude);
            endingLocation.setLongitude(destination.longitude);

            //Find the Bearing from current location to next location
            float targetBearing = startingLocation.bearingTo(endingLocation);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                    new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
                            .bearing(targetBearing)
                            .tilt(90)
                            .zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                            .build();
            //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(createLatLngBoundsObject(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), destination), width, (height - 200), padding));

           mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


        }
```

**EDIT:** rotating marker.

```
 moveMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(cameraPosition.target.latitude, cameraPosition.target.longitude)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromBitmap(customMarkerDes)).flat(true).anchor(.5f, .5f).rotation(startingLocation.bearingTo(endingLocation)));
```

Comment: createLatLngBoundsObject() what will do this method??

Comment: that is for creating boundary and displaying the area  within that boundary. you can ignore that try  `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));`

Comment: just check this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think.nextstop are you looking for such feature. this is what i did.

Comment: This method is rotating map but i need to rotate marker